# livereload failing to compile

Tags: sass, compass, livereload

I'm new dev environments and to get to grips with sass. I've installed compass and a few other gems, Im trying to use live reload to help update the browser, but it won't play nice;

```
    LoadError on line ["55"] of /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb: cannot load such file -- compass/import-once/activate
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace 
screen.scss: compilation failed.
```

I'm not sure what's happening here, could any one shed a little light on the subject and preferably point me to a good resource?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue after a little more googling;

[LiveReload plugin](https://github.com/livereload/livereload-plugins/tree/master/SASS.lrplugin/gem/gems/compass-import-once-1.0.1)

Hopefully this ill help anyone else stuck in the same boat :)